# Regex to match word preceding parentheses, inside an specific XML tag

Tags: regex

I'd like to write a regular expression to match a word that requires two conditions.

1. Be inside an XML **action** tag. I wrote a regex for that:

   `([^<>])*(?=<\/action>)`
2. Match the word preceding a parentheses. Like this:

   `((\w+)(?=\s?\())`

Combining both expressions into one didn't work. Any ideas?

```
([^<>])((\w+)(?=\s?\())(?=<\/action>)
```

Using the following text, the regex should match all the occurrences of the word **add**:

```
<action>add();</action>

<action name="foo">add();</action>

<action>
   add();
</action>
```

Comment: Try `\w+(?=\s?\([^<>]*<\/action>)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/iz6lbQ/1)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Your regex also matches `<action>add(;</action>` which is incorrect as per OP. See demo, https://regex101.com/r/iz6lbQ/2 May be you should correct the regex to this `(\w+)(?=\s?\(\)[^<>]*<\/action>)` See demo, https://regex101.com/r/iz6lbQ/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the regex you are looking for which needs to satisfy your two regex conditions,

```
(?s)(?:<action[^>]*>\s*\K)\w+(?=\s?\(\).*<\/action>)
```

This regex will match your both conditions that are,

1. Word should be enclosed between `<action>` tag
2. Word precedes by a parenthesis

**Explanation:**

- `(?s)` --> Need to enable dot matching a new line as I see your tags can be spread in multiple lines.
- `(?:<action[^>]*>\s*)` --> This matches an action tag where action tag may optionally included any kind of attributes. Here \s* is to eat any white space which we don't want it to get matched with the word.
- `\K` --> Resets whatever matched, so only the word gets matched as per OP's post. Why I had to do this, because negative look behind group doesn't allow quantifiers and at the same time to make the regex robust by allowing it to match any variable length input inside  tag.
- `\w+` --> Captures the intended word
- `(?=\s?\(\).*<\/action>` --> Positive lookahead to ensure it is followed by `()` followed by zero or more any characters followed by </action> tag.

[Click here for demo](https://regex101.com/r/55Fq5V/1)

Also, the way you wanted this regex `([^<>])*(?=<\/action>)` to ensure it matches a word between `<action>` tags, this regex is not enough because it will also match this,

```
add</action>
```

which isn't enclosed in `<action>` tag.

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any queries further.

Comment: Your regex works and I marked your answer as correct. Unfortunately, I just discovered that it needs to complain .Net regular expressions, and it doesn't work. For example, \K isn't recognised. I'm going to ask another question in SO to keep things tidy.

Comment: @RafaelGP: `\K` is only there to reset the matched characters but if you don't need that and just want the regex to match, you can simply remove `\K` from the regex. Please check and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: The following .net regex works OK. `(?s)(?<=<action[^>]*>\s*)\w+(?=\s?\(\).*</action>)`